# how to change pivot point of extruded text to the edge of extrusion

Tags: extrude

Is it even possible to change the pivot point of an extruded text to the edge of extrusion?

I know how to change the pivot point, but i cannot set it to the edge of extrusion...

Comment: You mean an extruded text that is not converted to a mesh? Not as far as I know, since there is no real geometry to select and e.g. snap the 3D cursor to. So it would only be possible to try to put the cursor to the right place and set pivot point to 3D cursor, or set the cursor to some value where you know the XYZ position of the edge, for example you extrude it 1 m so you know the edge is at Z = 0.5 m or something like that.

Comment: yes, i mean and thought that...thank you